# When did multiple Enterprises meet after flying into an anomaly?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, episode-identification, timeline

I remember watching a Star Trek episode or movie, where multiple Enterprises from different times met after flying into an anomaly like thing, but I couldn't find anything on Google about it.

Does somebody remember anything like that from a movie or series?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: That happened many times, actually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are referring to *All Good Things*, the final (two-part) episode of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.

The episode revolves around an anomaly that grows backwards in time, as witnessed by Captain Picard, whose consciousness is subjected to time jumps between three eras. The episode culminates in Picard bringing the Enterprise into the anomaly in all three eras so they can join forces to dissolve the anomaly.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I searched for.

Comment: Funny, my first thought was "Yesterday's Enterprise" which features the *Enterprise*-C.

Comment: And, of course, [Parallels](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)), where multiple Enterprises from different time *lines* meet. [Quite a few Enterprises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc5KhfP4MIo), in fact.